# How to create tabs with input[type="radio"] in html using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a Tabs with `input[type="radio"]` using Jquery and my tab is working fine on first click, but it will not work when we click on the second click. I'm stuck on it and not getting where is the missing in Jquery. Can someone help me?

Here is the code link: [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/Devbuddy/nrcpL7s8/8/)

```js
$('.tablist').on('click', 'input', function(){

  var tabList = $('.tablist-content').attr('id');
  if($(this).attr('type','radio').is(':checked') || $(this).next('label').text() == tabList){
    $(this).parents('.tabWrapper').find("#" + tabList).show();
    console.log(tabList);
  }
  else {
    $(tabList).hide();
  }

});
```

```css
.tablist-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabWrapper">
<ul class="list-unstyled tablist">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="tablist" id="tablist1">
    <label for="tablist1">List1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
  <input type="radio" name="tablist" id="tablist2">
  <label for="tablist2">List2</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="tablist-content" id="list1">
    List one content
  </div>
  <div class="tablist-content" id="list2">
    List Two content
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: `$('.tablist-content').attr('id');` gets you the ID of the _first_ element with that class name found in the whole document. You failed to make _any_ connection to the actual radio button you are operating on here.

Comment: And `$(this).attr('type','radio').is(':checked')` makes little sense as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use data attributes

No need to test for checked or not.

```js
$('.tablist').on('click', 'input', function() {
  $(".tablist-content").hide()
  $("#"+$(this).data("id")).show()
});
```

```css
.tablist-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabWrapper">
<ul class="list-unstyled tablist">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="tablist" data-id="list1">
    <label for="tablist1">List1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
  <input type="radio" name="tablist" data-id="list2">
  <label for="tablist2">List2</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="tablist-content" id="list1">
    List one content
  </div>
  <div class="tablist-content" id="list2">
    List Two content
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you mplungjan! it's a one solution for as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.index()` method to determine the index of the clicked radio which should be the index of the tab to show.

Also consider using the `change` event which is only triggers upon change from unchecked to checked. On the contrary the `click` event triggers whether the `radio` was previously checked or not, unless that's your goal.

```js
$('.tablist').on('change', 'input', function() {
    var index = $('input[name=tablist]').index(this);
    $('.tablist-content').hide().eq(index).show();
});
```

```css
.tablist-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabWrapper">
<ul class="list-unstyled tablist">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="tablist" id="tablist1">
    <label for="tablist1">List1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
  <input type="radio" name="tablist" id="tablist2">
  <label for="tablist2">List2</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="tablist-content" id="list1">
    List one content
  </div>
  <div class="tablist-content" id="list2">
    List Two content
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```